# Rust variable 'does not live long enough' and 'conflicting requirements'

Tags: json, rust

I'm unfortunately having a lot of trouble managing lifetimes in Rust, relating to strings and structs.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;
use serde_json::Value;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs;
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Song {
    artist: String,
}

struct SongEntry {
    date: &'static str,
    song: &'static Song,
}

fn main() {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("./charts/").unwrap();

    let fileContents = paths.map(| path | {
        let p = path.unwrap().path();
        let file = File::open(&p).unwrap();
        let v: Vec<Song> = serde_json::from_reader(file).unwrap();
        return v.iter().map(move | song | {
            let date = p.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
            return SongEntry {
                song: song,
                date: date,
            };
        })
    });
}
```

I've tried *many* variations of managing memory here, but only seem to swap one error for another.

The intent is to iterate through JSON files in a directory, parse them, and assemble an vector of objects containing the date (from the filename) and the content (from parsed JSON).

So far I've tried declaring `date` within the inner `map`, or outside of it, tried using `Arc` to manage the `date` variable, tried the inner loop with and without the `move` keyword.

However, I just can't find a way to get the variable bindings in these `map` methods to last for the right amount of time. Any help would be much appreciated.

The current errors produced are:

```
   Compiling kanye v0.1.0 (file:///Users/tmcw/src/sandbox/kanye)
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:29:26
   |
29 |             let date = p.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime  as defined on the body at 28:42...
  --> src/main.rs:28:43
   |
28 |           return v.iter().map(move | song | {
   |  ___________________________________________^ starting here...
29 | |             let date = p.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
30 | |             return SongEntry {
31 | |                 song: song,
32 | |                 date: date,
33 | |             };
34 | |         })
   | |_________^ ...ending here
note: ...so that closure can access `p`
  --> src/main.rs:29:24
   |
29 |             let date = p.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
   |                        ^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:32:23
   |
32 |                 date: date,
   |                       ^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `kanye`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Meta-questions: is this an appropriate use of `map` in Rust, or should I be using normal iteration instead? I also tried iteration before, but also got stymied by memory checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store references in a struct, then those references must refer to objects that have an owner that will live longer than that struct. Furthermore, `&'static` references must refer to objects that will be valid for the whole duration of the program's execution. Neither is true for the `date` and the `song` fields.

Here, the `SongEntry` struct should simply own the `date` and `song` objects.

```
struct SongEntry {
    date: String,
    song: Song,
}
```

For the `date` field, simply convert the string slice (`&str`) into an owned string (`String`) with the [`to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) method. For the `song` field, you need to move ownership from the vector `v`. However, [`Vec::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) only yields borrowed references to its items. You must use [`Vec::into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_iter) instead, which returns the values directly, consuming the vector in the process.

```
fn main() {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("./charts/").unwrap();

    let file_contents = paths.map(|path| {
        let p = path.unwrap().path();
        let file = File::open(&p).unwrap();
        let v: Vec<Song> = serde_json::from_reader(file).unwrap();
        v.into_iter().map(move |song| {
            let date = p.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().to_string();
            SongEntry {
                date: date,
                song: song,
            }
        })
    });
}
```

At this point, `file_contents` is an iterator over iterators of `SongEntry` objects (the outer iterator iterates over files, the inner iterator iterates over the entries in a file). If you would rather like to have an iterator of `SongEntry` objects directly, use [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) instead of `map` on `paths`. You can then use [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) on the final iterator to collect the results into a vector, if necessary (don't use `collect` if you're only going to iterate on the results once!).

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and thorough answer! Explains so much.